# div height in percent, and unwanted scrollbar

Tags: css, html

http://magicdynamic.com/fit/

in this demo page i have 2 problems:

1) My footer (I followed those guidelines http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) is causing a scrollbar to appear on Firefox only, and I can't understand the reason

2) div#containerTop is used by the footer css and it fits the whole page height

```
    min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height:100%
```

the problem is that I would like to have div#rightContainer with a certain height, i would like it to stretch for almost the whole page, (leaving some pixel between it and the footer). Obviously i tried with height in % and it didn't work.

I tried some CSS i found around but those didnt work too, probably because div#rightContainer is already inside a div container using itself a css height trick.

What can I do without recurring to javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use % as height you have to put that in every parent element:

```
<body style="height: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
```

maybe you could set the container absolute, but that not really a proper coding style.

Answer (score 0):

First set div's parent height and width to 100% and set overflow in html tag to hidden as:

```
html{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden; 
}
body{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

and then set your div's width and height accordingly......

Here overflow property does the task. If now body exceeds the width/height of actual window size then reduce the size of body tag accordingly.
But this will surely remove the scrollbars.

It worked for me.